# Manhwa where the female lead, a fangirl of the novel, gets reincarnated in it as a side character

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation

Female lead has white hair and gets reincarnated as an ordinary side character. She is a fangirl of second love interest and pays a lot of money to go into balls to see him. He had long white hair and a big chest.  Then she married him to save him from doing suicide as he loves the original female lead. The original female lead has pink hair and is like a saintess and she married the duke. I don't think it's completed yet.

Answer (score 2):

Except for the colour of the female lead's hair (black, not white) this sounds almost exactly like [*For My Lost Love*](https://harimanga.com/manga/for-my-abandoned-love/chapter-1/comment-page-1/) or *For My Abandoned Love*/*For My Derelict Favorite*.

> I was transferred to a romance novel that I liked so much that I almost choked on the last episode. I'm a commoner, but I have a lot of money. I watched from afar as the protagonists of the original novel acquired the status of a fallen nobleman. I thought I was returning to reality after the end of the novel... Somehow after the end I got rid of the possession and lived life in the novel. As a result, I even learned behind-the-scenes stories that I didn't want to know about. My favorite protagonist, Caelus, died. While living in poverty in the novel without him, I fell ill and died. I thought I was finally returning to my reality, but I returned to the end of the novel at night. This definitely…

The original female lead, Diana, is a saintess who has healing powers and pink hair, the second male lead, Kaelus, has long white hair.

[image: A pink-haired woman in a blue dress walks away from the viewer on the arm of a tall, dark-haired man in a white uniform with gold piping and epaulets and a half-cloak. Narration reads "Only then did they meet." Narration for the following image reads "Lovely pink hair, reflecting a soft, pearlescent shine. Bright eyes that swirl the mysterious hues of a green sea."]
[image: Portrait of the pink-haired woman, smiling, still in the blue dress. The caption reads "Heroine Diana"]
[image: Cartoony reaction shot of the narrator saying "It's the heroine after all! It feels like I'm choking on air!" The narration for the next portrait begins "Dazzling black hair and golden orbs the most perfect man, excelling both in body and face."]
[image: Narration continues "Even with a birthright as Crown Prince" followed by a portrait of the man in uniform, captioned "Male Lead Helios"]

[Some rambling elided...]

[image: Narration reads "Anyway- beautiful, handsome, cool, a man you will never find even if you search the entire world. A visual of the century!!!" "The second male protagonist of the novel!!!" A portrait of a man with long white hair wearing a black shirt, white tie and a purple suit with the caption "2nd Male Lead Kaelus"]
[image: Another cartoon reaction shot of the narrator proclaiming her love for Kaelus: "That's right! My bias, my favourite! It's my baby!!!!" and "I love you!"]